# Onclick of item Sending position of the gridview to the listview to fetch data from sqlite database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, gridview

I'm developing music related Android App. I have sqlite database having data about album,tracks,release year,lyrics etc... I have a Gridview,fetched album names from sqlite and displayed in the gridview succesfully. On clicking an item in gridview a new activity with listview displaying tracks of that album must be created. On clicking an item in the listview a new activity displaying the remaining datas of that track must be created. I'm new to android and i need help with this. Thanks in advance.

My Cursor adapter

```
public class CursorTrackAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public CursorTrackAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_song, parent, false);
}
public static Bitmap getImageFromBLOB(byte[] mBlob)
{
    byte[] bb = mBlob;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bb, 0, bb.length);
}
// The bindView method is used to bind all data to a given view
// such as setting the text on a TextView.
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    // Find fields to populate in inflated template
    TextView tvBody = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Label"));
    tvBody.setText(body);

    ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(getImageFromBLOB(cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("Cover"))));



}
```

My Album fragment Class

```
public static class AlbumsFragment extends Fragment {


    public static AlbumsFragment newInstance() {
        AlbumsFragment f = new AlbumsFragment();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout resource that'll be returned
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_album, container, false);

        DatabaseOpenHelper handler = new DatabaseOpenHelper(getContext());

        SQLiteDatabase db = handler.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor todoCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM album", null);

        GridView gv = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        CursorAlbumAdapter todoAdapter = new CursorAlbumAdapter(getContext(), todoCursor);

        gv.setAdapter(todoAdapter);
        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                for (position=0;position>=0;position++) {
                    Intent toActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), PlaySong.class);
                    startActivity(toActivity);

                }
            }
        });





        return rootView;
    }
```

Need help in this SongList Activity class

```
public class SongsList extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_songs_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Here is my Database Opener class

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db.sqlite";
@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public final static String DATABASE_PATH="/data/data/PACKAGE_NAME/databases/";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
//public static final int DATABASE_VERSION_old = 1;

//Constructor
public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}

//Create a empty database on the system
public void createDatabase() throws IOException
{
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist)
    {
        Log.v("DB Exists", "db exists");
        // By calling this method here onUpgrade will be called on a
        // writeable database, but only if the version number has been
        // bumped
        //onUpgrade(myDataBase, DATABASE_VERSION_old, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    boolean dbExist1 = checkDataBase();
    if(!dbExist1)
    {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try
        {
            this.close();
            copyDataBase();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

//Check database already exist or not
private boolean checkDataBase()
{
    boolean checkDB = false;
    try
    {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        checkDB = dbfile.exists();
    }
    catch(SQLiteException ignored)
    {
    }
    return checkDB;
}


private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
{
    String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myInput.close();
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
}

//delete database
public void db_delete()
{
    File file = new File(DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);
    if(file.exists())
    {
        file.delete();
        System.out.println("delete database file.");
    }
}

//Open database
public void openDatabase() throws SQLException
{
    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);


}

public synchronized void closeDataBase()throws SQLException
{
    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    if (newVersion > oldVersion)
    {
        Log.v("Database Upgrade", "Database version higher than old.");
        db_delete();
    }
}
```

For your reference I include screenshot of my database design[DatabaseTrack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoVBP.png)

[DatabaseAlbum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIskC.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What exactly is your issue and question?

Comment: Need some advice on how the data fetched from sqlite could be displayed in greidview,listview(with respect to the position of click item) and in some activity. How to use cursor in my situation?

Comment: Is your GridView showing items ?

Comment: Yes my gridview works fine. I need help with the list view and the rest

Comment: I have SID in both of the tables. If SID from table Album matches with SID from table Track,then the corresponding SID's contents(Track with same SID's) should be listed in listView.  need help with Java Code.

Comment: Could any one understand my problem?